# How to fetch data from localstorage of a browser synchronously in Angular

Tags: angular, local-storage

It seems to be a very simple task. I've written the code and it is working also. But there is a small issue. First let me show you the code:

**navbar.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

  currentUserFirstname="";
  currentUserLastname="";

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.currentUserFirstname=localStorage.getItem('firstname');
    this.currentUserLastname=localStorage.getItem('lastname');
  }
}
```

**navbar.component.html**

```
<span class="current-user">{{currentUserFirstname}} {{currentUserLastname}}</span>
```

I just want to display the current logged in user which I've to fetch from storage. The problem is that, it is never displayed first time. See, after the green circle there's nothing:
[image]

But when I refresh the page once. The values appear. See:
[image]

I tried using `setTimeout()` but it didn't work:

```
ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(function(){
      this.currentUserFirstname=localStorage.getItem('firstname');
      this.currentUserLastname=localStorage.getItem('lastname');
   }, 2000);
  }
```

Please help me. I need help making the code synchronous for this task.

Comment: You can use the service to store the names and fetch it from there onInit.

Comment: I think it is a design issue, such as the component is created before having information in the storage. Try to do a `console.log` on the `ngOnInit()` method for the firstName / lastName.

Comment: @MohitKumar
Oh Ok Sir.
So is it not achievable with simple boiler plate code?

Comment: @HTN, you are right. I tried console log. It is giving me `<empty string>` for both.

Comment: The navbar component should be created dynamically on user's login, or it should listen to this event to update user's name.

Answer (score 0):

By the time your code gets executed, are you sure the values have been set to the localStorage yet?

It sounds like you would set them on any later event and of course if you refresh it had been set.

Comment: Yes, actually the moment user logs in, the first and the last name of the user gets stored in the local storage. And the problem that i asked above is post login issue.

Comment: And also I've noticed that sometimes it shows the name of the previously logged in user. But again, when i refresh the page, its shows the correct name.

Comment: It really does sound like you only localStorage.setItem after you read it here.
Make a console.log() for every place you read/write the data and assure the order.

Comment: Jimmy you are right. Its my fault actually. It is giving me `<empty string>` for both the values. I'm trying to make a common service between the Login code and Navbar code.

Comment: Best practice here would be to create an BehaviorSubject from rxjs and fill it with localStorage values on first init, but when the user logs in/out update the BehaviorSubject and localStorage

Answer (score 0):

Local storage works even in the constructors so please check or add debugger there and check if the local storage consists the value before the function tries to get it from the storage